# NodeJS Forever package minUptime and spinSleepTime warnings

Tags: node.js, forever

I'm trying to run the forever function for node.js but I get below warnings;

```
C:\serv>forever start SERVER.js
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up f
or at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: SERVER.js
```

How to set `--minUptime` and `--spinSleepTime` to remove these warnings

Installed `forever` package with `npm install forever -g`

Comment: Why do you need to change them?

Comment: Because i get the error in the description

Comment: That's not an error, 'warn' means it's a warning which you can choose to ignore.

Comment: But this wont load the js file when i look at forever list nothing will showed up

Comment: Well that's another problem. Your script is crashing. You don't want to prolong it if it's got a bug, you want it to crash. Try running with `node SERVER.js` and fix the bug first before starting it with forever.

Comment: There are no errors if i run node SERVER.js

Comment: if trying with node SERVER.js is running fine then you might need to look at how you run with forever

Answer (score 22):

These are only warnings. You could go on ignoring them, if you want.
But if you want to explicitly set them, `forever --help` tells you how to do so. Just start `forever` with:

```
forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 SERVER.js
```

Comment: But it don't load the file i thought the warnings needed to be fixed. And with your line i get CreateProcessW: Can't find the file while im in the folder where SERVER.js is placed

Answer (score 22):

The documentation is not very exhaustive, a bit of additional information.

In the following examples we will use two scripts:

fail-fast.js:

```
process.exit(1);
```

fail-slow.js:

```
setTimeout(() => { process.exit(1); }, 2000);
```

### 1) using defaults

```
forever fail-fast.js
```

`fail-fast.js` script will execute **only once**, then no other start attempts will be made.

```
forever fail-slow.js
```

`fail-slow.js` script will be **restarted indefinitely**, as it stays up more than 1000ms (default value of `minUptime` if not specified). You can limit the number of restarts with the `-m` parameter.

### 2) setting only `minUptime`

```
forever --minUptime 10000 fail-fast.js
forever --minUptime 10000 fail-slow.js
```

Both `fail-fast.js` and `fail-slow.js` will be **never be restarted**, because we extended `minUptime` to 10 seconds and now `fail-slow.js` is considered spinning.

### 3) setting `spinSleepTime`

Whenever you set `spinSleepTime` (with or without `minUptime`), **your process will restart even if it is considered 'spinning'**.

```
forever --spinSleepTime 30000 fail-fast.js
forever --spinSleepTime 30000 fail-slow.js
```

Both scripts will be **restarted forever**, waiting `spinSleepTime` milliseconds between restarts.

Comment: You might want to clarify point (3). It will only restart if it fails. Obviously both of your scripts fail, but I don't think the difference is clear.

Comment: @Cully When you say it will only restart if it fails do you mean it wont anyhow restart when it does not exit? Is there a possibiilty where even with spinSleepTime, your script does not restart when it fails? Is there a specific type of failure where this can happen?

Answer (score 4):

In short:

```
When stop
    if hadRunTime >= minUptime 
       restart 
    else if spinSleepTime != 0
         wait spinSleepTime
         restart
    else 
         stop and no restart
```

@Megadix The answer has something wrong with `spinSleepTime`.
`fail-fast.js` will restart wating `spinSleepTime`,but `fail-slow.js` will restart immediately,no waiting! It can be Proved by:

```
 console.log((new Date()).getTime());
 setTimeout(() => {
    process.exit(1);
   }, 2000);
```

output like:

```
1468812185697
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #1
1468812187766
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #2
1468812189834
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #3
1468812191901
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #4
1468812193977
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #5
1468812196039
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #6
1468812198107
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Script restart attempt #7
1468812200172
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
forever start --minUptime 1234 --spinSleepTime 3421 SERVER.js
```

https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#usage

Comment: It gives me back `forever --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 SERVER.js` but it doenst load it

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you are using express module that is way after you using - forever start SERVER.js - your server is not running, because express module run server in path ./bin/www - so you should use this command - forever start ./bin/www --name="SERVER" - name is the name of your js file, by default app.js

Comment: The errors they are referring to are just warnings.  @cyprian